# How can I configure apache to handle backslash in URLs as 400-Bad Request

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, apache2

My apache server is visited with `\` (backslashes) in URLs such as

```
http://myhost.org/this\is\a\hacker\attempt.html
```

According to [RFC 2396, section 2.4.3](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/2396/full.html#2.4.3) the `\` character in URLs are not allowed (`%5C` should be used instead) . For that reason I would like to configure apache to respond 400 Bad Request every time such character is in the request URL.

How can I configure apache to do that? Can I use mod_rewrite for that?

Comment: OK. I misunderstood the apache log. The real case is that I get requests containing UTF-8 characters on that is I HTTP reqeust like `GET http://myhost.org/æble` where the `æ` is the two bytes C3, A6 (in UTF-8), so that shows up in the apache log as `GET /\xc3\xa6ble`. Using UTF-8 in URLs should be done with `GET http://myhost.org/%C3%A6ble`. However I want apache to respond a 400 Bad Request in the case the HTTP request contains UTF-8 characters that are not percent encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more general question over at serverfault which contains the answer for this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/451521/how-can-i-configure-apache-to-respond-400-when-request-contains-an-invalid-byte